# Easy way to move all html links up a directory

Tags: html, directory

I have a webpage I have placed in a subdirectory for organization such as

```
/internal/internalstuff.html
```

Now I would like the `internalstuff.html` to easily reference all of the other files from the top directory such as stylesheets.

Is there an easy one-liner to make all links reference the next directory up, or do I need to hardcode all the links like

```
"../stylesheet.css"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this really easily by using the [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag. Just put the following in the `<head>` tag on your site:

```
<base href="http://example.com/">
```

That automatically changes all relative urls to start from the base url `http://example.com`.

Comment: Perfect! The only thing was put this `<base href="...">` tag at the top of the head section.

Answer (score 1):

In pure HTML - no way :(

You need some backend magic for this.

Comment: Any way with .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to.

If you can use PHP, you can do something like this:

```
<?php
  function getResource($res) {
    return "../" . $res;
  }
?>
```

and in your page file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php getResource('stylesheet.css'); ?>">
```

But as your project is as small as it only needs to use html, i would not recommend this. Also, it's longer than hardcoding.

Okay, right, you CAN use .htaccess files:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\.css$ /yourfolder/stylesheet.css [L]
```

Give it a try, i'm not completely sure, but if you want to be sure you can read about the htaccess module mod_rewrite. Also your server needs to support this module.